# find marginal density of $X$ where $X,Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)=c\cdot \exp (-(2x+3y))$ over the region $x>0$ and $x<y$.

Tags: probability, integration

Find marginal density of $X$ where $X,Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)=c\cdot \exp (-(2x+3y))$ over the region $x>0$ and $x<y$.

I've found that $c=15$ for the joint density to be normalized. Then I used 
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y) dy&=&15\int\limits_{0}^{x} e^{-2x}e^{-3y} dy\\
&=&15e^{-2x} \int\limits_{0}^{x}e^{-3y} dy\\
&=&15e^{-2x} \left[    -\frac13 e^{-3y}    \right]_{y=0}^{y=x}\\
&=&5e^{-2x} -5e^{-5x}
\end{eqnarray*}
for $x>0$ and $0$ else. So this is what I've found as the marginal density of $X$. However $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx = \frac32 \neq 1$. So this $g$ is not a proper density for $X$ and I've made a mistake somewhere. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: to get the marginal of $X$, why do you integrate from $0$ to $x$? It should be from $x$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks a lot! can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bounds on integration are wrong. You should integrate from $x$ to $\infty$ ot get $\frac{1}{3}e^{-5x}$, then multiply by $15$ to get the standardizing constant $\frac{1}{5}$ and it neatly integrates to $1$.